# Dialog not dismiss in if condition

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am try to dismiss dialog in if condition true part but it is not worked.
In dialog entered in if condition but not dismiss.in If condition toast message display properly.

```
public void showIncomingCall() {

        int getTotal = 0;

        if(showincoming != null && showincoming.isShowing() )
        {
            //adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //showincoming.dismiss();
            return;
        }
        else {
            showincoming = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            showincoming.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            showincoming.setContentView(R.layout.custome_dialog);
            listdialog = (ListView) showincoming.findViewById(R.id.incoming_list);
            //adapter1 = new CustomeListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            listdialog.setAdapter(adapter1);
            //adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
             close = (ImageButton) showincoming.findViewById(R.id.dialog_close);

            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    showincoming.dismiss();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

            for (int i = 0; i < listdialog.getCount(); i++) {
                parentView = getViewByPosition(i, listdialog);
                String getString = ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.tvLineStatus)).getText().toString();

                if (getString.toString().equals("Idle") || getString.toString().equals("Disconnect") || getString.toString().equals("Dialing")) {
                    getTotal += 1;
                }
            }
            if (getTotal >= 7) {
                    showincoming.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"getTotal" + getTotal,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //adapter1.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,getTotal+"getTotal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listdialog.invalidateViews();
            if(!showincoming.isShowing()) {
                showincoming.show();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You are logically calling dismiss() before show() method, why?

Comment: basically you cant do this as when your dialog is open...your main activity will be paused...so its code will not execute...you have to dismiss dialog from opened dialog itself

Comment: I am try to dissmiss dialog even after dialog dismiss i put toast after dismiss that toast display properly but dialog not dismiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showincoming = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);` 
declare this below `int getTotal = 0;`
 i.e outside `else` statement 
then you can get referance of dialog object and can dissmiss dialog. try this and let me know

Comment: I am try that thing but does not worked even after dismiss diaog i call toast that worked perfectly :(

Comment: this happens only when the object you used to show dialog is not available to dismiss dialog, try to write only dialog.show method inside the loop or if-else statement. declaration and initialization should done at method or class level

Comment: oh thanx i will try this

Comment: Yes i try but dismiss does not worked becuase in else part dialog object initialized with second heap index.and i want initialize object in else part becuse if dialog alredy shown then it not update listview but new dialog generate